# When are cohomology operations determined by their action on coefficients?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology-operations

It is well-known that K-theory operations are determined by the action on coefficients, but I don't know the right way to prove this fact, nor a reference for the same. On the other hand, clearly this is not true for ordinary cohomology operations. In general, when will this be true, and how does one prove it?

Does this make sense to ask also even for unstable operations?

Comment: Are you asking when the map $\pi_*F(E,E)→\mathrm{Hom}_{\pi_*\mathbb{S}}(\pi_*E,\pi_*E)$ is injective? You can interpret it as a statement about the universal coefficient spectral sequence (i.e. that everything above the 0-line dies) but I doubt it's all that helpful...

Comment: @DenisNardin maybe the OP means something slightly different since most interesting operations on K-theory are not linear, hence not represented by maps $K\to K$.

Comment: @DylanWilson Right, but in that case why are they talking about unstable operations as if they were a different thing?

Comment: i guess the main question is about stable, hence linear, operations, and then a secondary question is whether we can also say anything about the non-additive ones.

Comment: I'm not sure what can be said at this level of generality. Probably one place to start that's doable is to figure out whether this property holds for Landweber exact cohomology theories. (In particular: is this true of MU? This feels like something I should just know but the answer doesn't seem to be filed away like it ought to be...)

Comment: @DylanWilson This is indeed true for MU, see Lemma 4.1.15 of the green book.